# Check what attributes have been assigned to component in Emberjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, htmlbars, ember-components

I wrote a component to display a select modal dialog.

```
{{m-modal-select value=valList valuePool=possibleValueList}}
```

This is a multi-select component, `valuePool` is the candidate list, `value` is the selected list. Now I want to support both multi-select and single-select within this component, when it is single mode, the code should be like this:

```
{{m-modal-select singleValue=selectedOne valuePool=possibleValueList}}
```

I wish the component itself can recognize whether it is in single or multiple mode by watching which attribute(value or singleValue) is assigned to it.

I don't know how to achieve this in component js.

Additionally, I also wonder if there is a function to get all assigned attributes' names in component. For the above two examples, it would be like below:

```
this.get('assignedAttrNames');  

//the first one 
// ['value', 'valuePool']

//the second one
// ['singleValue', 'valuePool']
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.get('attrs')` will give an object with the attributes that you passed to the component.

To check if single select or multi select

```
//component.js
if(this.get('singleValue')){ 
  //single select code 
}else{
  //multi select code
}

//component.hbs (only if you need so)
{{#if singleValue}}
single select code
{{else}}
multi select code
{{/if}}
```

Comment: for instance, `{{x-comp username}}` , `username` is a property in related controller. Is there anyway both the attr name('username' here is) and the value can be accessed in the component?

Comment: If you use `{{x-comp username=username}}`, Then calling `this.get('attrs')` from component will give you the attributes.